# node.js refresh DOM on POST request

Tags: node.js, dom, http-post

I'm a beginner in node.js and I'm trying to create a simple local hosted webpage that automatically refreshes itself (DOM) and displays information that was received through a POST/GET request. I've been googling for hours and haven't found anything that worked. I'm not even sure if node.js is used for this kind of stuff.

edit: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Node.js Receiver</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="someEl">some element</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        let _html = '';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            _html += chunk.toString();
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            console.log(_html);

            res.render('index.html'); // "res.render is not a function"
            res.end(_html); // doesnt update website in browser
            document.body.innerHTML = _html; // error
        });
    }
    else {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        res.end('nothing');
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague and doesn't include any info on how you're rendering and serving, but to get information from a request back to the browser, you'll generally want to pass something from the `request` to the `response`. In bare Node, you could do this with `req.pipe(res)`.

I'd recommend *not* using plain Node's `http` on its own, though. I would look into ExpressJS, or Hapi or Koa. Express is probably the most popular web framework for Node. It would allow you to host static files with `express.static()`, and templating languages like EJS to get your data from the server back up to the client.

Comment: This is just a project I'm doing for myself. I'm not aiming for it to look good or be secure. I want my C++ app to send data over post requests to my browser and then display it. If I could get this started simply by appending html body with the post content that would work just fine, but I don't know how to use Express or EJS. Are there any tutorials where I can learn to do what I need specifically?

Comment: Express is simple. I mentioned in my other post not to use a framework, but express is a node framework for setting up a server and it will make your routing easier. I would recommend reading documentation here:
 https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

But if you want something straight forward, watch this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8XF6AFGqlc

or just watch this which is specifically for express:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnsO8-xJ8rs

ejs (embedded javascript for server side rendering with parameters) is pretty simple. Learn that after everything else is done imho

Comment: Okay, here is a good EJS tutorial that also uses express:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

If you want to get more advanced I recommend moving on from EJS to something like react or vue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are trying to do is

```
setInterval(function(){
  XMLHttpRequest()
  .done(function(httpResponse){
    var el = document.querySelector('#someEl');

    el.innerHTML += httpResponse.body.html
  })
}, 3000);
```

On the server side you could have the node server render out some kind of template using ejs or handlebars. I prefer ejs(embedded javascript) because I get nightmares IRL from squiggly braces it's true. So to install and save EJS you need to do:

npm install ejs --save

The save, afaik, is used to save it to your package.json dependency list.

Tell the entire app to use this rendering engine like this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))
```

And in whatever router you're doing after you do a post or get, and want to send a response do this:

```
res.render('partials/account', { 
  foo: ser.idu,  
})
```

The reason ejs is useful is because you can create dynamic pages using logic to render the page on the server depending on whatever logic was run on the server in reaction to the user's request.

You embed some logic in your HTML and the server will render it, and send it back.

And in your case, using setInterval you can have that done every 3000ms or however many milliseconds you want.

Comment: setInterval definitely sounds like what I need, but I still don't understand how I could piece this code together. I just started with node.js yesterday and the tutorials on w3schools have been easy to follow but I don't know anything about ejs or rendering engine or handling requests :/ I only have experience with javascript and C++ which I would use to send these post requests to the server (via C++ app). I have pieced the code that you provided to the best of my abilities and put it in my original post but it's not enough. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Since you're working on your first app I would recommend trying to simplify the amount of things you are trying to learn or do. For instance, don't use websockets, or a frameowrk like Angular, even Vue. People will tell you Vue is simple, but even if Vue is simple, you still have to learn webpack, which can be a huge PITA. The stuff I put up there isn't actual code. So the 3 things you need to learn are: Make http get request from client side. On node, use ejs to render an HTML template, and do res.render('path/to/template'), then when you get the response back, append to the document.